# Массив объектов в JSON

Tags: массивы, json, объекты

По стандартам JSON он может содержать в себе объекты. Могут-ли быть эти объекты разнородными? Например, будет корректна следующая запись?

```
{ "g_params":
    [
        { "id": "b01",     "caption": "p_nom_rt",
        "type":  "real", "value": 220000.0, 
        "min":   0.1, "max": 999999.0,
        "units": "u_kgh"
        },
        { "id": "b02",     "caption": "p_nom_sp",
        "type":  "real", "value": 1.0, 
        "min":   0.1, "max": 10.0,
        "units": "u_mps"
        },
        { "id": "b03",     "caption": "p_fdr_dim",
        "type": "list",  "value": 0, 
        "text_arr": ["l_fd1", "l_fd2", "l_fd3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

В стандарте на http://json.org/json-ru.html сказано, что массивы могут содержать объекты, но не сказано, что элементы массива должны быть однотипные. Означает-ли это, что они могут быть разнотипные, что могут быть вложены объекты разного формата?

Comment: да, конечно могут быть разнотипные. это же вообще элементы массива, а ему всё равно (почти), что туда ты ему засунешь..... Остается вопрос - нужно ли это делать?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , спасибо за ответ! Тогда разница между объектами и массивами заключается только в упорядоченности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно могут.

```js
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    [1, 'array', {was: 'with'}, {some: ['strange', 'things']}, null],
    null,
    '  '
  )
)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: none; }
```